# Burninate [codepen]?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The [codepen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/codepen) (115 questions) seems quite misused. It seems a lot of questions have this tag just because the OP created a codepen to show their problem, not because the question itself has anything to do with codepen.

But, I don't think codepen meets the four criteria for burnination as explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191). So I am not sure what is the correct solution to this.

The four criteria:

1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous? - **No**
2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site? **Not sure**
3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post? **Not always**
4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts? **Yes**

One more thing, [jsfiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsfiddle) (1440 questions) might also have similar problems.

Comment: I think this might need a cleanup instead of being burned.

Comment: @NathanOliver:  I'm tentatively agreeing with you...provided we find some examples of questions which won't come immediately under fire during the cleanup effort despite them *maybe* being on-topic.

Comment: *Chris Coyier does not approve*... /s

Comment: Break the [codepen]?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It seems to me that quite a few of the [`[codepen]` questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/codepen) *are* actually about CodePen and how code hosted on CodePen behaves differently than code hosted elsewhere.

My opinion is that:

- the tag can stay because, even though it is an external site, it is a tool used by programmers and issues with CodePen should be interesting to programmers.
- the tag should be removed from questions where it is inappropriate.
- the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/codepen/info) is a plagiarized sales pitch and needs to be improved with actual information <s>and usage guidance</s>.

Comment: I agree cleaning it is the correct choice in this case. Should I go ahead and clean-up or is there a procedure for this?